# Replace all the ".net clr" in user agent

Tags: php, regex

I am learning regex and I am testing some string lookup/replacement on the user agent.

I have few user agent with:

- .NET CLR 11432
- .NET CLR 2.0.2648
- .NET CLR 1.0.1369
- .NET CLR 2.0.90283

I can replace the ".net clr \d" but it does no work properly.

```
  $ua = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 4.1; .NET CLR 12858)';

  $r = preg_replace('/.NET CLR \d/i', '', $ua);

  var_dump($r);
```

and i get:

Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 4.1; 2858; .0.6143)

clearly i am missing something, but what?

thanks

Comment: do you want to replace just the `.NET CLR` or the number that follows too?

Comment: @AmitJoki the number too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex doesn't adhere to the decimal point of the version number, that's why it's matching everything up until the `.`. Change you regex to this:

```
$r = preg_replace('/\.NET CLR [\d\.]+/i', '', $ua);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `\d+` also escape the dot(`.`):

```
$r = preg_replace('/\.NET CLR \d+/i', '', $ua);
```

If you want to remove digit(`0-9`) + dots(`.`) then

```
$r = preg_replace('/\.NET CLR [\d.]+/i', '', $ua);
```